# Display values of array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, session, object

How can I dialplay  values of array of objects which is stored into session.

I make like this

//fetch array of countries from db

```
$countries = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $country = new Country();

        $country->setCountryName($row['country_name']);
        $country->setCountryNo($row['country_no']);
        $country->setCountryZipCode($row['country_zipcode']);

        $countries[]=$country;
    }

$_SESSION['countries']=$countries;
```

then display the values of the session like this

```
<select name="countries" id="countries">
        <?php foreach ($_SESSION['countries'] as $i=>$country ){?>
        <option><?php echo $_SESSION['countries'][$i]=>$country.getCountryName()?></option>   //here's the error
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

The error occurs when I display the values of session, any help plz?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\AppServ\www\crm\subpages\SearchCustomer.sub.php on line 14 .
line 14 is where I print session values

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo $country->getCountryName(); ?>
```

Comment: This error occurs : main() [<a href='function.main'>function.main</a>]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Country&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in C:\AppServ\www\crm\subpages\SearchCustomer.sub.php on line

Comment: I assume the two snippets you posted in your question are from two different scripts. In which file is the `Country` class defined? You need to include that file in the script that displays the `<select>` element.

Comment: I already include the country file which have the country class, I try to make echo 'hi'; it works and loop as the number of returned countries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save objects within session. I'm sorry. But you can store those as array of properties and restore it each time the script starts.

Comment: Are you sure we can't save objects within session in php ??

Comment: You will need to use serialization:
http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/569329-forgot-storing-objects-session-php-5-2-0-a